# Issue when installing OpenCv using Pip

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I need help to install OpenCv with Pip.
Everytime I type the `pip install opencv-python` command in the command prompt, I get this error :

```
C:\Users\me>pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.4.0.44.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in e:\python\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.19.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'e:\python\python.exe' 'e:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphs6y6kyz'
       cwd: C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l8x74op7\opencv-python
  Complete output (153 lines):
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l8x74op7/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l8x74op7/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l8x74op7/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l8x74op7/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l8x74op7/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-l8x74op7/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.9 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: By the looks of things you have Python 3.9. Try an older version of Python, as some packages are not yet available for 3.9. And you probably don't have Visual Studio installed, which is required to compile the module. Please update your question with the required information.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try this.

Comment: In case you want to stick to Python 3.9, you can also try using wheel files from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv download and then install the wheel files that are failing. This worked for me for some packages.

Answer (score 0):

If there are unoffical wheels available, then the easiest way to install it would be.

```
pip install pipwin
```

then

```
pipwin install opencv-python
```