# Installing OpenCV using pipwin in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I first created a new environment opencv then installed pipwin. Afterwards, I tried installing opencv by entering

```
pipwin install opencv-python
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Scripts\pipwin.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\pipwin\command.py", line 28, in <module>
    from . import pipwin, __version__
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 13, in <module>
    import js2py
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\js2py\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from .base import PyJsException
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\js2py\base.py", line 2965, in <module>
    @Js
     ^^
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\js2py\base.py", line 165, in Js
    return PyJsFunction(val, FunctionPrototype)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\js2py\base.py", line 1377, in __init__
    cand = fix_js_args(func)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\js2py\utils\injector.py", line 27, in fix_js_args
    code = append_arguments(six.get_function_code(func), ('this', 'arguments'))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\anaconda3\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\js2py\utils\injector.py", line 121, in append_arguments
    arg = name_translations[inst.arg]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 3
```

I tried this: [Issue when installing OpenCv using Pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64500580/issue-when-installing-opencv-using-pip)

But it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you use `pipwin` instead of the standard `pip` package manager?